# Java giving error :incomparable types: boolean and int" even though both methods are boolean?

Tags: java, compare, palindrome

What Im trying to code is that a user inputs a number n and the program outputs all the numbers from 1 to n that are both prime numbers and palindrome numbers. 
I created a method for finding prime numbers and another for finding if a number is a palindrome. My code for outputting the integers that are both goes like

```
if ((prime(y)==true) && (pal(y)==n)) {
            System.out.println(y);
        }
```

Here is my method for finding prime numbers:

```
public static boolean prime(int n) {
    int x = 2;
    while (n%x>0) {
        x+=1;
    } if (x==n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my method for finding palindrome numbers:

```
public static boolean pal(int n) {
    int rev = 0;
    int rmd = 0;
    while (n>0) {
        rmd = n%10;
        rev = rev*10 + rmd;
        n = n/10;
    } if (rev==n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the error that these two methods are not comparable because apparently one is boolean and the other integer. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When you compare the two methods, in the secod comparation: `if (pal(y) == n)` you are comparing boolean (pal) with an integer (n)

Answer (score 3):

Your statement says `pal(y)==n`, but `pal(y)` returns a boolean. I'm not sure what comparing it to `n` is supposed to do.

In general, avoid statements like `foo == true`. If it's already a boolean, just use `foo`, or for false `!foo`.

Comment: OH THANK YOU, it was just a silly mistake on my part